# How do I delay my message by one second? UDP client

Tags: c, udp, client

I'm making a program to send and receive messages over a network, I currently have it set up to repeat the message 50 times, but I'd like it to delay each message by one second. Is there a way I can do this using select? If not, how else can I do it?

Thanks.

Here's the code for my client

```
void
client (char * servername) {
   ssize_t     bytes;
   int         skt;
   char        buff[BUF_SIZE];
   int i;

   do{
   skt = createsocket ( servername, PORT );

   bytes = (ssize_t) sprintf (buff, "Hello %s, sequence number:", servername);

   if (write (skt, buff, bytes) < bytes) {
      fprintf (stderr, "WARNING: write didn't accept complete message\n");
   }

   memset (buff, 0, BUF_SIZE);
   bytes = read (skt, buff, BUF_SIZE);
   if (bytes < 0) {
      perror ("read()");
      exit (1);
   }

   printf ("Server echoed the following: %s\n", buff);
   i++;
   }while(i < 50);
}
```

P.s. I'm also going to try to add a sequence number in there using a long type, how would I go about this?

Comment: Can't you simply add *sleep* (http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) or *nanosleep* (http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep) at the end of your loop? These are for Linux, but I'm sure all OS should have an equivalent.

Comment: OT: "*"WARNING: write didn't accept complete message\n*" why not loop around `write()` resending what was left until everything has been sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be reasonably close to what you want.  (Did not test.)

```
void client (char * servername)
{
    ssize_t bytes;
    int skt;
    char buff[BUF_SIZE];
    int i = 0;
    long seqNum = 0;

    skt = createsocket ( servername, PORT );

    do
    {
        memset (buff, 0, BUF_SIZE);

        struct timeval t = {1, 0};

        select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &t);

        bytes = (ssize_t) sprintf (buff, "Hello %s, sequence number: %ld", servername, seqNum++);

        if (write (skt, buff, bytes) < bytes)
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "WARNING: write didn't accept complete message\n");
        }

        memset (buff, 0, BUF_SIZE);

        bytes = read (skt, buff, BUF_SIZE);

        if (bytes < 0)
        {
            perror ("read()");
            exit (1);
        }

        printf ("Server echoed the following: %s\n", buff);
        i++;
    }
    while (i < 50);
}
```